# Creating and uploading to specific folders in Azure Blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload files to Azure blob storage via C# code, however, I need a specific directory tree. My code so far:

```
BlobServiceClient bSC = new BlobServiceClient(MY_CONN_STRING);

string filename = $"test/files/file.json";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(filename);
var containerClient = bSC.GetBlobContainerClient("mycontainer");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);

using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

I have other piece of code that generates a file in `test/files/file.json`. In Azure blob storage, however, I want it to be uploaded to the directory tree of my choosing. Example: `/mycontainer/Events/production/file.json`, whever `Events` needs to be created as well.
Right now it is recreating the tree structure within my project of `test/files/file.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String parameter in `GetBlobClient` is responsible for "path" your file will have once uploaded, it should not be exactly the same as file name in your local system.

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("mycontainer/Events/production/file.json");
```

Comment: One important piece of information to add for OP, Azure Blob Storage uses a flat paradigm to represent blobs, you can make it "look" like it's hierarchical but you should know that's an _abstracted_ lie. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet#flat-listing-versus-hierarchical-listing for more.

Comment: This was what I was looking for and not understanding. Thank you